# Find the Sunflower subgraph induced in a graph in polynomial amount of time.

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

A subgraph Sn of a graph G is a sunflower graph, if consists of a Cycle Cn = {v1,v2,..,vn} of n vertices together with other n independent vertices {u1,u2,...,un} such that for each i, ui is adjacent to vi and vj, where j = i-1(mod n).

Comment: A graph could contain 0, 1 or (many) more sunflower graphs as induced subgraphs.  Do you need a particular one?

Answer (score 1):

You could think of a sunflower - in the sense of the question - as a cycle of triangles. In time O(N^3) you can check each triple of points to see if it is a triangle and create a new graph whose vertices denote triangles in the original graph and where two vertices are linked if the two triangles share one or more vertices.

Then a depth first search looking for back edges should find cycles in this graph. Not all cycles are good. I think it may be enough to check that no two successive edges in the supposed cycle in the derived graph are  produced by the same vertex in the original graph, and that you can check this as part of the depth first search. It may take some detailed analysis of cases to establish this, unless you can find a neat proof.

Comment: Are you suggesting creating a new graph G' that contains a vertex for each triangle and an edge between every pair of vertices that represent triangles that share 1 or more vertices?  Sounds promising, but I see 2 problems: (1) adding any vertex to a subgraph of G' can add more than 2 edges to the induced subgraph (I think this could be solved with a modified DFS); (2) a chordless cycle in G' doesn't necessarily correspond to a sunflower in G anyway, because it might be e.g. {abc}--{cde}--{cfg}(--{abc}), and here the triangle {cde} can have no edge participating in the sunflower's cycle.

Comment: Looks good.  I think my counterexample in (2) applies only to length-3 G'-cycles: for a cycle in G' of length >= 4 to contain a "bad" vertex like v = {cde} that has just 1 G-vertex participating in the sunflower's cycle in G (rather than 2, indicating an edge), it must be that the vertices on *both* sides of v in this cycle also contain this G-vertex (here c), implying that there must be an edge between these 2 neighbours of v in G'.  So if the DFS guarantees to find only chordless cycles, then if it finds one with length >= 4, it *must* correspond to a sunflower in G.

Comment: But...  I'm not sure if the DFS can be poly-time, because we might need to try adding some edge uv to the end of the current path many different times.  A separate, minor point: I think vertices in G' should be linked only if *exactly* 1 G-vertex is shared between them.

Comment: If there are triangles with two shared vertexes then you could either ignore the pair or treat it as a smallest possible sunflower depending on our interpretation so yes you might want to treat this as a special case either way. I had thought of the DFS as standard with one extra constraint, so as usual it never marks and extends from any vertex more than once and its cost is at most |vertices| * |edges| - can you explain why this might not be the case?

Comment: The question of whether it's legal to add some vertex v to the end of the current DFS path depends on the set of vertices already in the current path (because that determines how many back-edges v would create, and we want to forbid choices of v that create >= 2 back-edges), which I had thought would be a problem.  But I see now that even if v would create >= 2 back-edges, it's OK to add it anyway, since exactly 1 of those edges will form the "tightest loop", and that will contain no chords, so we can then pick that as the cycle.  *Except...* for the case of my counterexample (2)...

Comment: If we just avoid adding any edge uv to the current DFS path if it, together with the previous edge xu, would create a problematic "triangle of triangles" that only share a single vertex in G, then we run the risk of missing a cycle in G' that contains uv but not x.  I think it will suffice if, whenever we avoid adding such an edge uv, we also add uv to a "TODO" set of edges, which will be investigated after the current DFS completes by separate DFSes that start with each edge in turn.  This should be doable in O(|E||V|+|E|^2) (I think a single DFS will take O(|V|+|E|) time, not O(|V|*|E|)).